# error in using sqrt function for unit

Tags: matlab

I am executing this code which contains the following line of code:

```
sf_den=sqrt(sf_den+a*b);
```

But I am getting the following error,I cannot figure out why

```
Undefined function or method 'sqrt' for input arguments of type 'uint8'.
```

Value of a is 0 and b is <171x210x3 uint8>
What should i do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Convert the data to a type that **is** supported by `sqrt`.  For example:

```
sf_den = sqrt(double(sf_den + a*b));
```